# How to force VS 2013 to rebuild database from scratch for ASP .NET MVC 5 project

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

What steps one must take to force Visual Studio and Entity Framework to delete current used database and then generate it from scratch basing on class in model directory for ASP. NET MVC 5 project?

EDIT: If it it necessary I will repeat: **from scratch**.

EDIT2: My Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using WebApplication2.Migrations;
using WebApplication2.Models;


namespace WebApplication2 {
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {

            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PersonContext, Configuration>()); 
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PersonContext>());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

PART OF WebConfig

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.PersonContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Models.PersonInitializer, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: @BradChristie I have `DatbaseInitializer`. I do not ask about updating database. It already exists. I ask for exacly what is stated in OP.

Comment: I'm aware, however there is a `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T>` `DatabaseInitializer` you can use.

Comment: @BradChristie EDIT2. It never works I have tried this stuff for hours before, this is way I asked the question the way I asked.

Comment: Faced with that problem, I would simply drop the database on SQL Server, redefine it however i need to, and then have VS 2013 create the model as "ADO Entity Model",  I'm probably not doing things the new way and requires a little more work, but at least I'd know what I was doing and what I should expect to see.